# Implementing fresco inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to use fresco inside my recyclerview fragment to display images from drawable resource folder and network eventually. How can i fully implement fresco i am a newbie at android dev. this is my code so far in my adaptor and its bringing errors.

```
final String path = "res:/" + R.drawable.fetchimage003;
holder.mainImageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the path of image from the drawable folder like this

```
final String path= "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```

or

```
final String path = "android.resource://com.yourpackagename/drawable/imagename";
```

and then set String path as imageURI to image view

ivProfileImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));

Comment: Thank you i will try it out